# Where can I see turtles hatching or laying in southern or south-western Sri Lanka in late March?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, sri-lanka

Are turtles hatching or laying eggs in southern or south-western Sri Lanka in late March?

Which area would I need to visit to see turtles on the beach at this time?

Comment: What's "best"? Cheapest? Most turtles? Least crowded?

Comment: @MarkMayo Edited to remove subjective "best"

Answer (score 5):

Two districts Galle and Hambantota Has turtle hatching:

> A total of 13 selected beaches in the Galle district and eight beaches in the Hambantota district were studied. The total number of nests was 2224 in Galle and 1764 in Hambantota. The nesting rate in the Galle district was 185 nests.month-1 and nesting density was 110 nests. year-1km-1, while in the Hambantota district the nesting rate was 147 nests.month-1 and nesting density was 140 nests. year-1km-1

I found on this link: [Classification of Sea Turtle Nesting Beaches of Southern Sri Lanka](http://www.arbec.com.my/sea-turtles/art25julysept01.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Turtle Conservation Project (TCP) Sri Lanka is a non-Government organisation.  The TCP website indicates volunteers would be placed at [Kosgoda, Kalpitiya or Rekawa](http://www.tcpsrilanka.org/index.php?page=volunteering).  Of these, Kosgoda and Rekawa are in the Southern Province.

The [Kosgoda Sea Turtle Conservation Project](http://www.kosgodaseaturtle.org/) offers tours of thier project for 400 rupees.

East of Galle at Habaraduwa, is the [Sea Turtle Farm and Hatchery](http://www.seaturtlefarm.org/).

North of Galle, turtles may be seen at Hikkaduwa.

Based on various videos posted on youtube, turtles lay in Febuary and early April, so they should be laying during March (if the moon/tide is right).